Non-Causal and Causal Wiener filter for Smoothing
I am trying to solve a smoothing problem using a wiener filter solution. I have tried to setup and compare three different solutions in matlab: A FIR filter solution, a general causal solution, and a non-causal solution. Unexpectedly, I am finding that the FIR solution has the best performance.
In my toy problem I have a sequence I wish to estimate, $U$, and an observation sequnce, $Y$, where $Y = U + W$ where $W$ is some white noise source. The three solutions are found as:
FIR coefficients: $c = R_{YY}^{-1} r_{U,Y} \quad$
where $R_{YY}$ is the auto correlation matrix of the observation sequence. $r_{U,Y}$ is the cross correlation vector between $U$ and $Y$.
Non-Causal filter matrix, $K$: $K = R_{Y,U} R_{YY}^{-1} \quad$ where $R_{Y,U}$ is the cross correlation matrix between $U$ and $Y$.
Causal filter matrix, $K$: $K = [R_{Y,U} L^{-*}D^{-1}]_L L^{-1} \quad$ where $R_Y = LDL^*$ (so an LDU decomposition for a hermitian matrix) and $[]_L$ is notation to denote the lower triangular part of a matrix.
For the non-causal and causal solution I have used the description from to help guide me:
Linear Estimation by Thomas Kailath, Ali H. Sayed, and Babak Hassibi (chapter 4).
(Alternatively: https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jiantao/225a2020spring/scribe/EECS225A_Lecture_7.pdf)
Here is a minimum viable example implemented in matlab:
rng('default')
nsampl = 1000;  % Number of samples to generate for the process.
samples = (1:nsampl)';
omega = 0.1;

phase_shift_1 = pi/4; % Phase shift
amplitude_1 = 0.8;      % Amplitude shift
noise = randn(nsampl,1);

% Generate the original sine wave signal and observed filtered sequence
u = sin(omega * samples);
y = amplitude_1*sin(omega * samples + phase_shift_1)+noise;

fir_order = 200;
w_fir  = wiener(u,y,fir_order, 'FIR');
tempy = [y;zeros(fir_order,1)];
u_est_fir = w_fir*tempy;
u_est_fir = u_est_fir(1:nsampl);

w_causal = wiener(u, y, length(y)-1, 'causal');
u_est_causal = w_causal*y;

w_ncausal = wiener(u, y,length(y)-1, 'non-causal');
u_est_ncausal = w_ncausal*y;

% Calculate and display error variances.
error_variance_noisy = mean((u-y).^2);  % Variance of the noise in the measurement.
error_variance_est_fir = mean((u-u_est_fir).^2);  % Variance of the estimation error.
error_variance_est_causal = mean((u-u_est_causal).^2);  % Variance of the estimation error.
error_variance_est_non_causal = mean((u-u_est_ncausal).^2);

disp(['Error variance of noisy signal: ', num2str(error_variance_noisy)]);
disp(['Error variance of estimated signal using FIR: ', num2str(error_variance_est_fir)]);
disp(['Error variance of estimated signal using Causal: ', num2str(error_variance_est_causal)]);
disp(['Error variance of estimated signal using Non Causal: ', num2str(error_variance_est_non_causal)]);


function w = wiener(u, y, order, method)
    % wiener calculates the Wiener filter matrices.
    % Calculate cross-correlation and auto-correlation coefficients for the given order.
    [ruy, lags] = xcorr(u, y, order); % Get cross-correlation and lags for u and y.
    ryy = xcorr(y, y, order);         % Auto-correlation with a maximum lag of order for y.
    
    % Find the indices for correlations from zero-lag to the specified order.
    zero_lag_idx = find(lags == 0);
    
    % Construct the correlation matrix R and cross-correlation vector p.
    Ry = toeplitz(ryy(zero_lag_idx:end)); % Toeplitz matrix using auto-correlation values.
    p = ruy(zero_lag_idx:end);           % Cross-correlation vector.
    
    switch method
        case 'FIR'
            % Solve the Wiener-Hopf equations to find filter coefficients.
            coef = Ry \ p;

            % Convert to matrix representation
            w = zeros(length(y)+order);
            for i = 1:length(y)
                w(i:i+length(coef)-1,i) = coef;
            end
        case 'causal'
            [L,D] = ldl(Ry);
            Ruy = toeplitz(p); 
            w = tril((Ruy / L') / D') / L;
            %equivalent to w = tril(Ruy*inv(L')*inv(D'))*inv(L);
        case 'non-causal'
            Ruy = toeplitz(p);
            w = Ruy/Ry;
            %Equal to w = (tril(Ruy*inv(L')*inv(D')) + triu(Ruy*inv(L')*inv(D'),1))*inv(L);
    end
end

As can be seen from the result, it seems that the FIR solution has best performance! Would any one have any idea why? Have I misunderstood something during my reading? or perhaps my implementation is fauly?
Error variance of noisy signal: 1.2695
Error variance of estimated signal using FIR: 0.023717
Error variance of estimated signal using Causal: 0.030692
Error variance of estimated signal using Non Causal: 4.0006

Any help is greatly appreciated!
